# Google Chart : How to get selected chart type from jQuery

Tags: javascript, google-api, visualization

I am working google charts.

I want to get selected chart type from jQuery.

From below **var chart** I want to get chart type (ColumnChart here).

```
var chart= new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('Graph1'));
```

I tried below as well:-

Created a new variable and assign chart-type to it.

```
var chartType3 = 'ColumnChart';
var mychart = new google.visualization.window[newchartType](document.getElementById('Graph1'));
```

but still not working..

Comment: Is there any errors in console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'chartType3' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

By taking another variable and store window[newchartType] in new taken variable and replacing function name by [chart32], I get the result.

```
  var chartType_ = window[newchartType];          
  var mychart = new google.visualization[chartType_](document.getElementById('Graph1'));
  mychart.draw(window[newData], window[newoptions]);
```